# выхлоп асма linux gcc с -O2 и без

Tags: c, ассемблер

есть функция

```
int foo(int num) {
if(num)
    return 1;
else
    return 3;
}
```

мне понятен выхлоп без оптимизаций:

```
foo(int):
  pushq %rbp
  movq %rsp, %rbp
  movl %edi, -4(%rbp)
  cmpl $0, -4(%rbp)
  je .L2
  movl $1, %eax
  jmp .L3
.L2:
  movl $3, %eax
.L3:
  popq %rbp
  ret
```

но совершенно не понятно что происходит с O2:

```
foo(int):
  cmpl $1, %edi
  sbbl %eax, %eax
  andl $2, %eax
  addl $1, %eax
  ret
```

зачем вообще использовать SuBtract with Borrow...
к тому же если заменить возвращаемое значение return 3 на return 2, то вообще как-то странно все отрабатывает

```
 foo(int):
  xorl %eax, %eax
  testl %edi, %edi
  sete %al
  addl $1, %eax
  ret
```

проясните немного что куда кладется при оптимизациях... а то что-то не могу въехать никак

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Компилятор не обязан генерировать понятный и/или простой для понимания код. С другой стороны если провести все вычисления на бумажке для всех входов и выходов, то логика работы функции будет точно такая же:

```
foo(int):
  cmpl $1, %edi    # устанавливает CF, если %edi-1<0 т.е. если %edi==0
  sbbl %eax, %eax  # %eax = CF ? 0xFFFFFFFF : 0
  andl $2, %eax    # %eax &= 2 т.е. в зависимости от CF: %eax=={2|0}
  addl $1, %eax    # %eax += 1 т.е. %eax=={3|1}
  ret
```

Во втором случае всё проще, можно переписать в примерном псевдокоде Си:

```
 foo(int):
  xorl %eax, %eax   # int rv=0;
  testl %edi, %edi  # if(num==0)
  sete %al          #   rv = 1;
  addl $1, %eax     # rv++;
  ret               # return rv;
```

Идея этих оптимизаций в том чтобы избавиться от команд условного перехода, которые на современных (i586+) ЦП, если блок предсказаний не угадывает, вызывают сброс конвейера, а следовательно значительно замедляют вычисления.

Comment: хм, походу надо разобраться с основами мне... CF этот не ясен

Comment: @xperious, CF — это Carry Flag. устанавливается если операция вызвала беззнаковое переполнение/антипереполнение. `cmp a,b` по сути устанавливает флаги в точности аналогично `sub a,b`, отличаясь только тем, что результирующий регистр не изменяется. т. е. если `b<a` (в синтаксисе at&t), то `b-a` вызывает беззнаковый underflow, который и устанавливает флаг CF.

Answer (score 5):

Если вы поэкспериментируете с разными константами в качестве возвращаемых значений в вашей функции

```
int foo(int num) 
{
  if(num)
    return A;
  else
    return B;
}
```

то можно заметить, что в общем случае в режиме `-O2` компилятор в качестве оптимальной стратегии вычисления результата выбирает следующий подход

```
int foo(int edi) 
{
  int eax = edi ? 0 : 0xFFFFFFFF; 
  eax &= B - A;                   // `B - A` - константа
  return eax + A;
}
```

Комбинация

```
cmpl $1, %edi
sbbl %eax, %eax
```

это ни что иное, как эффективный способ вычислить значение оператора `?:`. А дальнейший код тривиально соответствует вышенаписанному.

В случае же, когда возвращаемые константы отличаются не более чем на 1, компилятор выбирает другой подход - через `sete`.

Comment: хм, не знал что в eax можно класть что-то кроме возвращаемого значения

Comment: @xperious: В смысле? Да, к моменту завершения функции в `eax` должно сформироваться возвращаемое значение. Вот именно оно в `eax` здесь и формируется.